# ORACLE APEX: Dynamically Change a chart

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

Say I have created a chart as a modal dialog using the create a page tool in apex for a movie database project. I have imported an existing table from sql database. This modal dialog is linked to an interactive grid. For the modal dialog I have created an hidden ID item (id of movies) and a name item looking like this:
[items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykqD6.png)

If I run the program it looks like this:
[movie_database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7jz8.png)

I now want to dynamically change the votes in my chart (Count(User_Rating)), which means instead of hard coding the where clause (id = 1) it should be something like

```
id = :P14_ID
```

But it didn't work for me:
[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHziy.png)

What I am doing wrong? Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're saying isn't what you did (at least, that's what the last ("data") screenshot suggests). Should probably be

- where clause: `id = :P14_ID`
- order by: probably irrelevant, leave it empty
- page items to submit: `P14_ID`